# How can I remove duplicate versions of files starting with `._` created when moving files from PC to Mac?

Tags: command-line, files, macbook

A very capable young man installed Ubuntu on my Mac, but I don't know how he did it.

When I copy files to my MacBook Pro from another "ordinary" Ubuntu PC I find a lot of duplicate files with the prefix `._` (dot underscore).

On searching the Internet I find that all replies to this question are related to OSX.

Not being very techie, I would appreciate someone sending me a terminal command to wipe all files on my Ubuntu-Mac which have the prefix `._`... unless of course this will do something disastrous!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove files with `rm`, but as you already guessed that command has its risks. To prevent disasters there's the `safe-rm` package, so I recommend to install this first with:

```
sudo apt install safe-rm
```

It will automatically prevent you from removing anything important to the system.

Now to list every file beginning with `._` in the current directory do:

```
ls -1 ._*
```

To remove all files beginning with `._` in the current directory *asking for every single one* do:

```
rm -i ._*
```

To remove all files beginning with `._` in the current directory *without asking* – **Caution!** – do:

```
rm ._*
```

To do this recursively you can use the `extglob` functionality which needs to be enabled using `shopt -s extglob` (once per terminal window where you want to use it). After that you can do

```
rm -i **/._*
```

and it will remove every `._` file in the current directory as well as its subdirectories (and ask for every single one, you guessed it).

The asterisk `*` is a special character to the shell and simply matches any string, so `._*` matches any file beginning with `._`. The globstar pattern `**` followed by a `/` matches directories and subdirectories and needs the `extglob` option, which is not enabled by default.

Comment: I was going to add to my thanks to "dessert" - my best wishes for 2018 when I inadvertently  touched the enter button.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know about the "check". Thanks again